# How to get rid of exception on ChangeManager SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, active-directory, api, webhooks

I am working on SharePoint site notifications using webhook. I have added webhook subscription using the following reference [Get started with SharePoint webhooks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/get-started-webhooks). I have got **Notification** from the previous steps and then I passed it to the **ProcessNotification()** of the [ChangeManager.cs](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-samples/blob/master/Samples/WebHooks.List/SharePoint.WebHooks.Common/ChangeManager.cs) class.

As i debugged the program, I am getting the following exception on Line No. 81 cc.ExecuteQueryRetry() in ChangeManager.cs:

```
Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.
```

How to can I get rid of this exception and get changes detail on the site?

Comment: can you point out the code line where you get this error in ChangeManager.cs?

Comment: @Akshay Randive On Line No. 81  **cc.ExecuteQueryRetry();** in ChangeManager.cs.

Comment: I think the issue is with App permissions. this blog can help you https://medium.com/@ankitgirgas/how-to-debug-sharepoint-webhooks-locally-66f25e02654d